# Virtual Box error after creating new VM

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-8.1, kali-linux

I have followed several tutorials thinking I was doing something wrong while installing virtual machines using VirtualBox.

It is important to say that I'm running Virtual Box on Windows 8.1

The problem is that after creating a virtual machine, I get the following error when trying to start it.

[image]

```
---------------------------
VirtualBox - Error In supR3HardenedWinReSpawn
---------------------------
Error relaunching VirtualBox VM process: 5<br>Command line: '81954AF5-4D2F-31EB-A142-B7AF187A1C41-suplib-2ndchild --comment Kali --startvm 823fc23c-d310-4972-b3ef-6c40742d89f3 --no-startvm-errormsgbox' (rc=-104)
---------------------------
Abort   
---------------------------
```

I even thought that I could have downloaded a faulty VirtualBox version so I downloaded it again to find out that wasn't problem.

Not only have I tried creating Linux Virtual Machines but Windows virtual machines as well.

I found very little info in google concerning this issue... it is stated that it could be caused by another program such as an antivirus. I have tried uninstalling some programs and disabling my antivirus yet I have found no success.

Thanks for taking the time to read this. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this link (https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=62615), where the same issue has been discussed in VirtualBox forums. This appears to be happening in Windows host with certain Antivirus packages. I am putting this up as an answer just because I don't have "Comment" privilege yet!

Note: You haven't mentioned the VirtualBox version you are using (I assume it is the latest verion). But appears downgrading it to a lower version resolves the issue.

Comment: yes, indeed it's the latest version. (4.3.14). I will try a different version of Virtual Box... and I'll get bak to you.

Comment: 4.13.15 solved the issue. However, this is still a test version. I might downgrade to an older version until .15 becomes stable

Comment: 4.3.16 has been released and includes the fix

Answer (score 0):

I had to download [version 4.3.12](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.12/VirtualBox-4.3.12-93733-Win.exe).

This is the only version that I could find, and it worked for me.

I could not find a newer version on the virtualbox.org server. I did find version 4.3.14 RC1, but it didn't work for me.

If anybody is interested, the location with all available versions of VirtualBox is [here](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox).